# Adding margin to MenuItem in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a text menu on the right of the Toolbar with a left margin of 16dp. Does anyone know how to set the 16dp margin by adding to the following code?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    final MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 100, Menu.NONE, getString(R.string.menu_done));
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using java:

```
View view = new View(this);
menuItem.setActionView(view);
view.setPadding(16,0,0,0); //left , top ,right , bottom
```

Or XML :

Add this style to your toolbar , for your icon.

```
 <style name="myToolbarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
</style>
```

Of course if you have more items , you'll need to create a particular style for that item that you want left padding.

Comment: This will replace what has been added to the menu though.

Comment: Well I guess you could add text and even an icon , but if you want to maintain the order between icons , I don't think so . Sorry , I tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Due to answer of @Lazai
My implementation

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    View view = new View(getApplicationContext());
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewUtil.dp2px(16),
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    MenuItem space = menu.findItem(R.id.space);
    space.setActionView(view);
    //...
    return true;
}
```

where `ViewUtil.dp2px(16)` is

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static int dp2px(int dp) {
    float density = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round(dp * density);
}
```

Works fine and not clickable